# Summing data across various time periods into a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets. The first is an income statement for an individual company. It looks like this:

[image: figure 1]

The second is a combined sheet for the parent company that will be buying these individual companies. It looks like this:

[image: figure 2]

As you can see in Figure 2 d4, you can change how many new acquisitions the holding company makes each year, and this gets added to 'Total Portfolio Companies' in d5.

My challenge, is that I'm trying to figure out how to write a formula to correctly sum the numbers in d7 and e7, and account for the fact that not all the companies start in the same year. I'm currently using the following formula in figure 2: `='Figure 1'!H4*D5` This references the cells in figure 1, and multiples them by the total number of portfolio companies. This doesn't work quite right, as it assumes both new and existing companies start in year 3 when summing in figure 2 E7, for example.

My issue, is that I need to start counting all new acquisitions in year 1 (figure 1 column G), and count existing acquisitions in the year they were acquired. So figure 2 E7 would be counting a total of six companies, three that are starting the count in year 1 (figure 1 G4), two that are starting the count in year 2 (figure 1 H4) and one that is starting the count in year 3 (figure 1 I4).

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to do a `sumproduct` on figure 2 row 4 and reverse order of figure 1 row 4. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751620/reversing-a-list-in-excel-within-a-formula. Since this was written in 2018 you may be able to take advantage of some of the newer excel `sequence` function to reverse the order of figure 1.